# Piwik: Provide a simple opt-out link?

Tags: matomo

How can you provide a simple link to opt-out Piwik on your privacy site?

I've seen complicated iframe / php scripts from 2010, but I heard this would be plain simple, no?

Answer (score 0):

The opt-out iframe is still the solution to do that and the code is really simple: [Include a Web Analytics Opt-Out Feature on Your Site](http://piwik.org/docs/privacy/#step-3-include-a-web-analytics-opt-out-feature-on-your-site-using-an-iframe).

If you want to customize its appearance, you can have a look at this plugin: [CustomOptOut](http://plugins.piwik.org/customoptout).